# RTD in Excel VBA ( need to call data from rtd )

Tags: excel, vba, rtd

I was looking for the same answer where I need to call data from a RTD server

```
Sub Test() 
    Range("d1") = RTD("tickerplantrtdserver", , 4#2#1#6768#FUTSTK#N1#0#XX#Bid)
End Sub
```

When I extract data from Excel

```
RTD("tickerplantrtdserver", , 4#2#1#6768#FUTSTK#N1#0#XX#Bid)
```

it works fine and gives a number.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Range("d1") = [RTD("tickerplantrtdserver", , 4#2#1#6768#FUTSTK#N1#0#XX#Bid)]
```

`[]` brackets are shortcut for [`Evaluate`](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/evaluate.htm) Function.
So it can be written like this as well:

```
Range("d1") = Evaluate("RTD(""tickerplantrtdserver"", , 4#2#1#6768#FUTSTK#N1#0#XX#Bid)")
```

Take note of the double quotes in the `""tickerplantrtdserver""` part.
I have not tried this yet and have no way of testing but *Evaluate* works on formulas, so I am just assuming it will work the same with `RTD`.

Answer (score 0):

RTD is designed to return data continuously, but for the current value, try this:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Sub test()
   Range("D1") = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.RTD("tickerplantrtdserver", Null, "4#2#1#6768#FUTSTK#N1#0#XX#Bid")
End Sub
```

xlApp is slow, so you want to initialize once only

If you get a bad value, the server may not have a value yet, so try again a few seconds later

NB: Windows Excel only (RTD not supported on MAC)