# VBA Copy real time data value to another cell, same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, rtd

I have a formula in cell "D1" for receiving RTD, which works and get continuously updated data.
Now, I need a copy of this cell (only VALUE) in another cell "B2", same worksheet.
When i try the code I have found so far, the "B2" cell stays empty.
For test reasons I have copied another cell value (constant value) to "B2" and this worked.
Therefore, I believe there is a problem with copying RTD values.

I have started in the beginning with simply copying the values:

```
Sheets("New sheet").Range("B2") = Sheets("New sheet").Range("D1").value

or:

Sheets("New sheet").Range("B2").value = Sheets("New sheet").Range("D1").value
```

Then I have started to look for other solutions, like:

```
Sheets("New sheet").Range("D1").Select
enter code here`Selection.Copy
Sheets("New sheet").Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

or:

```
Sheets("New sheet").Range("B2").Copy Sheets("New sheet").Range("D1").value
```

Did not have success with this.

Then I played around with the interval the data in "D1" is received. Perhaps the copy code struggles with too frequent data. So i changed the Trottle Interval to several numbers up to 10.000, but this didn't change the result.

```
Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval=0
```

*Additional information:*
I enter the formula for receiving RTD data in "D1" directly before I copy the value to "B2".
Also tried the `application.Wait` function to give the data time to update, but since the macro freezes in this time, it made no change.
Moreover, have simulated a time delay with a while loop between entering RTD-formula and copy the values to the other cell.

Macro security settings: Enabled trusting VBA-projectObjectModul and all macros are active.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**:
I solved it by only placing the RTD formula in "D1" in the current sub and when this sub is finished, I call another sub that copies the value from "D1" to "B2" > This works.
It did not work by calling another sub in the current sub, it has to be finished first.

Thank you all for the input, appreciate! :)

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116721/rtd-in-excel-vba-need-to-call-data-from-rtd) help you?

Comment: I have just checked and `Sheets("New sheet").Range("B2").value = Sheets("New sheet").Range("D1").value` this should work. I duplicated this in a worksheet on my side using RTD too and it works. Possible questions to ask: a) What happens when you manually copy and paste? b) Are the cells locked for editing? c) What happens when you recreate this in a new workbook, perhaps you wb is corrupted somehow..

Comment: @Damian
I looked into it but i believe this is a different problem.

Comment: @Dean
It works if i do it manually with mouse. Actually the second code snippet in my post is the code of the recorded macro to copy the values.

Comment: @FabianS. if your approach doesn't work, you can always do as they say on that post, get the current value on vba, store it into a variable, or just print it on the cell you want.

Comment: Do `DoEvents` and/or `Sheets("New sheet").Range("D1").Calculate` help?

Comment: @Chronocidal Not completely sure where you would place these lines. Just tryed both seperately between the RTD command and getting the value of "D1". Did not work unfortunately